# Writing Custom Rewrite Rules that Incorporate Category for Custom Post Types?

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks

I'm registering a Custom Post Type and in the rewrite array I am trying to do something like this:

> `'rewrite' => array('slug' => "explore/resources/".$CATEGORY, 'with_front' => false)`

I want the rule to 'dynamically' get the post's category name somehow. I also tried using `%category%` there but it doesn't work either. I need the post's url to represent the entire path/route to it. Any ideas on how to achieve this?

**UPDATE:** Here is more clarification:

I have a custom post type of '`resources`' and these post have several different categories like '`forms`', '`mp3`' etc. now this Resources area in the site is under another section (that is a page with custom loop for those custom posts) which is called Explore. What I want to achieve is:

> domain.com/Explore/Resources/Resource-Category/Resource-Name

or

> domian.com/explore/resources/forms/production-form-1

My current rewrite rule in `register_post_type()` is:

> `'rewrite' => array('slug' => "explore/resources", 'with_front' => false)`.

Thanks!

Comment: @Amit: It's not clear what you are after. I'm not sure what you mean when you say *"'dynamically' get the posts's category name somehow"*. Can you please explain in more depth? Also, can you  please tell us what your Custom Post Type is and give several example URLs that you would like your system to produce?

Comment: @Mike, I have a custom post type of 'resources' and these post have several different categories like 'forms', 'mp3' etc.

now this Resources area in the site is under another section (who is a page with custom loop for those custom posts) which is called Explore.

what I want to achieve is domain.com/Explore/Resources/Resource-Category/Resource-Name or domian.com/explore/resources/forms/production-form-1.

my current rewrite rule (in register_post_type()) is 'rewrite' => array('slug' => "explore/resources", 'with_front' => false).

Thanks for the fast response!

Comment: I'm going to have to do some research on this one, assuming someone else doesn't answer it correctly before I do.

Comment: @Mike, I just saw the correspondence in the mailing list about taxonomies, custom posts and rewrites and your trac suggestion about the new controller, I guess that my issue is similar to what is described there so I´ll jut have to wait for some newer, more fit implementation.

Comment: Any chance you could make your WordPress database available somehow so that I could load it and not have to recreate your data in order to test this?  You could post the SQL dump file as a private gist at gist.github.com...

Comment: I kinda hit a wall with this approach and also something got totally messed-up with the rewrite rules (didn't help canceling, flushing nor deleting them) so I transitioned to a different one, but I'll try to recreate it, pack it (with the needed template files) and email you on the mailing-list email address. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use my plugin:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-post-permalinks/

That will only work if it's a non-hierarchical post type.

If it's hierarchical, you're going to have to register the permastruct yourself. This is a huge ordeal which I don't have the time to write out at the moment. You can look at the code in my plugin above and try to work it out for yourself. Some pointers:

- In order to get the category into the URL, you're going to have to hook into the `'post_type_link'`
- You'll also have to hook into `'parse_request'` to make sure the post type is recognized.

Comment: tried it and it doesn't let me add the %category%, my post types use it and are non-hierarchical.

Comment: Are you sure you registered categories for the post type? My plugin only does categories, not other hierarchical taxonomies.

Comment: You know, your question/response made me double check the code, and you're right, there was a bug there. I'm sorry about that. Categories should work for you using my plugin now.

Comment: thanks, this issue is fixed now but now I think I've found another bug and its doesn't let me do something like (only) /%category%/%resource% it instead adds before the %post_type%/ so it ends to be /%post_type%/%category%/%resource%.

Comment: Nope, that's intentional. It only does that if your permastruct mirrors the post permastruct. If your custom permastruct is the same as posts, everything breaks. WordPress matches everything against your custom post type instead of posts. They have to differ somehow.

Comment: well.. after 5 hours of different setups I have to say that it's quite a good plugin but it doesn't suit my needs.. things start to get nasty there also trying when also trying to remove the word 'category' that wp adds.. I'd really hope for a better solution wp-wise.

Comment: Thanks for the compliment on the plugin. For the category part, are you talking about the 'Category Base'?

Comment: Yes.. I'm now trying to create a new set of custom taxonomies instead of the CATEGORY built in taxonomy so I'll be able to mimic the same structure, but the plugin doesn't accept my new custom-taxonomy as a valid value. my new hierarchical taxonomy is calls 'resource_type' and trying to do /resources/%resource_type%/%resource%
thanks!

Comment: Yeah, the category thing is tricky. Since it is the only taxonomy that WordPress requires, it's the only one I felt safe including. But custom taxonomies will be included in a future version. You'd have to use a different tag for resource_type, since that tag is telling WordPress that it's the taxonomy view, but you need it to be the single view. Does that make sense? I'll try to get a looooong explanation up later this weekend.

Comment: not sure I understand.. so theoretically is there a 'wild-card' tag? how would you recommend constructing the page/categories/posts/post-types scheme then? you can mix and match them all but you can't keep uniform urls.

Comment: Eh spend a vote for John, he is so helpul to you.Spread some Kudos man :D